# Replace Obsolete AllTypes class in Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor

I have this code from old castle:

```
IoC.Container.Register( 
    AllTypes
        .FromAssemblyNamed(a)
        .Pick().WithService.FirstInterface()
        .Configure(o => o.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest));
```

When I upgrade to castle 3.2 I get this error:

> Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.AllTypes' is obsolete

And this error for **o.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest** :

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like @charleh said, `AllTypes` was replaced with `Classes` so fixing this problem is a simple find and replace.

Actually if you look at the compiler warning it should say:

> 'AllTypes' has been deprecated and will be removed in future releases.
> Use 'Classes' static class (if you want to just register concrete
> classes) or 'Types' static class (if you want to register interfaces
> or abstract classes too) instead. It exposes exactly the same methods.

The reason for this change was that `AllTypes` was a lie - it was only matching concrete (non-abstract) classes, so `Classes` is a much better name that better tells you what it really does.

As for the other problem, changing the property call to a method call will fix it:

```
Container.Register(
    Classes.FromAssemblyNamed(a)
        .Pick().WithServiceFirstInterface()
        .Configure( o => o.LifestylePerWebRequest()));
```

Or simpler yet, skipping the `Configure`:

```
Container.Register(
    Classes.FromAssemblyNamed(a)
        .Pick().WithServiceFirstInterface()
        .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Windsor ships with `BreakingChanges.txt` file which describes breaking changes and how to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that `AllTypes` is equivalent to `Classes` (I actually learned this this morning!)

So instead of

```
IoC.Container.Register(AllTypes.etc)
```

Use

```
IoC.Container.Register(Classes.etc)
```

Not sure about the other but quick bit of searching seems to suggest that the lifestyles are pluggable in 3.2, you may be missing a reference

Edit:

Ah: Looks like you have referenced the client build of Castle.Windsor dll - there's another build against the full .NET profile which contains the type you need - check your references

[PerWebRequest Lifestyle missing in Castle Windsor 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630349/perwebrequest-lifestyle-missing-in-castle-windsor-3-2)